# $project in $lookup aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

So I have the following document

```
{
    "_id": "5b7dfee3130dd4ff45288882",
    "name": "test",
    ...
    "list": {
        "_id": "5b7dfee2130dd4ff45288875",
        "name": "test"
        ...
    }
}
```

How should I go about projecting all of the main document's fields, while only projecting `list`'s `_id` and `name`, given that `list` was created through a `lookup` + `unwind` i.e.

```
{
    "$match": match
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "lists",
        localField: "list",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "list"
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$list"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main challenge is that you want **all fields from the main document** (since you do not know all of them) plus only 2 from the list.

This should do it:

```
{
  $project: {
    "_id": 0,
    "document": "$$CURRENT",
    "list._id": "$$CURRENT.list._id",
    "list.name": "$$CURRENT.list.name"
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    "document.list": 0
  }
}, {
  $addFields: {
    "document.list._id": "$$CURRENT.list._id",
    "document.list.name": "$$CURRENT.list.name"
  }
}, {
  $replaceRoot: {
    newRoot: "$document"
  }
}
```

It goes through few stages but gets the job done :). It would take the current document and only the list fields you want. Then it would remove from the current doc its list. Then it would add to that same doc the list (since that one is with the specific fields we want). Then it would add those fields to the document and lastly it would replace the root with that document.

[See it here working](https://mongoplayground.net/p/094iyVO_Nj4).

Comment: only problem is, that the main document may have many fields (some unknown), while I know exactly the fields I want for the list. I.e. `list.id` and `list.name`

Comment: Updated my answer with another option

Comment: that seems pretty cool, would an `unwind` work in making it an object again?

Comment: Not really since `unwind` works with arrays and `document` is an object.

Comment: I think I got it ... see updated answer

Comment: cool, forgot about replaceRoot, will mark as answer once I've tested, thanks. Edit: Just realised you had a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is quite simple with the mongodb version 3.6 [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation where you can use [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) within the `pipeline`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "lists",
    "let": { "list": "$list" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "list" ] } } },
      { "$project": { "name": 1 }}
    ],
    "as": "list"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$list" }
])
```