# limit fields in $lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**MongoDB DB version 3.4.18.**

I want to combine data from a foreign collection, but I don't want to have it's all keys, I want to make a limit, like this:

```
db.users.find({}, {password:0}, (err, docs) => {});
```

And this is my aggregation query:

```
let query = [
  {
    // match from first collection (activities)
    $match: {
      "_id": ObjectId("5be46f266e4a182384b3ae6a")
    }
  },
  {
    // limit fields from first collection (activities)
    $project: {
      "_user": 1,
      date: 1
    }
  },
  {
    // join a foreign collection - but how to avoice the password key? for example.
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "_user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user"
    }
  }
];
db.activities.aggregate(query, (err, docs) => {
  console.log(docs[0].user);
  return cast.ok();
});
```

And I have a sub question.

Why use `find` if I can use `aggregate` with a `$match`, instead of a query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exclude fields in $lookup aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950121/exclude-fields-in-lookup-aggregation) or [$project in $lookup aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976839/project-in-lookup-aggregation/51992692#51992692)

Comment: Replace with below `$lookup` stage if you are using mongodb **3.6**. `{ "$lookup": {
        "from": "users",
        "let": { "user": "$_user" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$user"] }}},
          { "$project": { "password": 0 }}
        ],
        "as": "user"
      }}`

Comment: Can you answer it with fixed of my code? I receive undefined..

Comment: If your above aggregate query is working and you are using mongodb 3.6 then just replace the `$lookup` stage with the above one.

Comment: I'm at 3.4, should update, or that there something working both?

Comment: If you can able to update then you should. Else you need to use `$project` at the end of the pipeline after the `$lookup` stage. Something like `{
    "$project": {
      "user.password": 0
    }
  }`

Comment: Could you please provide with a full code example based on what I've provided?

Answer (score 5):

**MongoDB 3.6, "nested" $lookup**

```
db.activities.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5be46f266e4a182384b3ae6a") }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "user": "$_user" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$user"] }}},
      { "$project": { "password": 0 }}
    ],
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$project": { "user": 1, "date": 1 }},
])
```

**Standard MongoDB $lookup**

```
db.activities.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("5be46f266e4a182384b3ae6a") }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "_user",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$project": { "user.password": 0 }},
])
```

Comment: This ain't working. This limit the fields of the origin collection.

Comment: @Raz Just use `0` with the fields which you don't want  in `$project`. Something like `{ $project: { fieldName: 0, fieldName2: 0 }}`